# Не отображается блок видео

Tags: html, css, scss

Имею данную ситуацию

```
`<div class="hml__video-container" class="video-container"><div class="video-button"></div>
            <video class="hml__video" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXlXNshaVzk"></video></div>`



`.hml__video-container {
display: flex;
align-self: flex-end;
align-items: center;
width: 600px;
max-height: 320px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: solid 1px #061e37;
background: url(../img/BGproject.png) center no-repeat;
background-size: 690px auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
&:before {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    content: "";
}
& video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

}

[image: описание]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Вариант**

Вставить видео как предлагает YouTube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gXlXNshaVzk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**2. Варинат**

Заменить вашу строчку

`<video class="hml__video" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXlXNshaVzk"></video>`

На эту

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gXlXNshaVzk"></iframe>`